# Is the graded symmetric algebra $\mathrm{Gr} \mathrm{Sym} A$ on an integrally closed domain $A$ also integrally closed?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Question: If $A$ is an integrally closed domain, which is f.g. k algebra over an algebraically closed field, then is $A'$ (defined in the edit below) also integrally closed?

(I am thinking about this in the context of Hartshorne Algebraic Geometry II.5.14, which is about projectively normal schemes. The question comes up as a lemma to one of his hints, which I have been unable to show.)

Edit: I mean (what I think is called the graded symmetric algebra, maybe not), the direct sum over $n \geq 0$ of A, with the same multiplication as in A, but keeping track of grading. In degree zero it is k. So, it is symbolically $A' = \oplus_{n \geq 0} A^{\otimes n}$, tensored over A, with the degree 0 part the base field k. (After identifying the $A^{ \otimes n}$ with A, the product of a in degree n with a' in degree m is aa' in degree n + m.)

Comment: What do you mean by the symmetric algebra on a ring?

Comment: @Qiaochu I assume he's treating it as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module, and then turning it back into a $\mathbb{Z}$-algebra.

Comment: @AreaMan: this is just $A[x]$ then, right?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan No, for instance it is not finitely generated. I will detail the description.

Comment: @AreaMan: I don't understand how this isn't just $A[x]$. After identifying $A^{\otimes n}$ over $A$ with $A$, take $a$ in degree $n$ to $ax^n$. How is this not an isomorphism to $A[x]$?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan You are completely right, and I was misunderstanding the geometric situation to say that the degree zero part was $k$. (Also my comment that it is not f.g. is of course wrong.) Thanks a lot!

Comment: $\oplus_{n \geq 0} A^{\otimes n}$ is the tensor algebra. It's not commutative because in general $a \otimes b \neq b\otimes a$. The symmetric algebra is usually defined by factoring out the ideal generated by $a \otimes b -b\otimes a,\, a,b \in A$.

Comment: @ToddLeason This whole question is a disaster of me not describing the ring clearly enough. (I couldn't see that it was the polynomial ring!) In the geometric setting that it arises it is a commutative ring - these tensor products are over $A$, and $A$ is a commutative ring to being with.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. In this case, as observed by Qiaochu, $A'=A[X]$ and the latter is integrally closed (see here: http://www.math.columbia.edu/~nava/Exercise_2.pdf).

Comment: @ToddLeason Yeah, I was being a real dummy. :) You'd think I'd be able to recognize the polynomial ring when it was staring me in the face. I even started manipulating an element I was calling $1_n$... haha. Thanks for the link, that was well explained.

Comment: Wait, in degree zero it's $k$. Seems you are using the subring of $A[X]$ with polynomials those constant part is in $k$. You'll have to check if the proof from the ex. adapts to this situation.

Comment: @ToddLeason That's what I thought at first, but that was because I made a miscomputation on the side of the geometry. In degree 0 it is just the stalk of the structure sheaf at a point $P$ (as it is in all degrees).